# Creating an intent to launch the system app “Files”

Tags: android

I would like to launch the **Files** app from my application. The app with this icon:

[image: Files icon]

This code below works for Android 9 to 11. In older versions it used the fallback option. But in Android 12 it is unable to create a launcher intent both for `com.google.android.documentsui` and `com.android.documentsui`. Is there a workaround for this?

```
public static void startFilesManager(Context context)
{
    try
    {
        // com.android.documentsui is the Files app on Android 9 and 11.
        // com.google.android.documentsui is the Files app in Android 10.
        // com.google.android.apps.nbu.files is Google file manager, this is used as fallback.

        String[] packages = new String[] {
            "com.android.documentsui",
            "com.google.android.documentsui",
            "com.google.android.apps.nbu.files"
        };

        Intent intent = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < packages.length; i++) {
            String packageName = packages[i];
            intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

            if(intent != null) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // If nothing is installed, navigate user to the store.
        if (intent == null) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packages[packages.length - 1]));
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("FileManager", "startFilesManager: failed to start", e);
    }
}
```

**Update** I have also tried with `Intent.CATEGORY_APP_FILES` as below, but it just throws an `ActivityNotFoundException`. This happens on any Android version (at least in an emulator, where Files is installed).

```
public static void startFilesManager(Context context)
{
    try
    {
        Intent intent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_FILES);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("FileManager", "startFilesManager: failed to start", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than hardcoding packages, perhaps you should be [using `CATEGORY_APP_FILES` instead](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_APP_FILES).

Comment: Are you sure that the device even has this app? Eg. on Samsungs file manager app is `com.sec.android.app.myfiles`

Comment: Great suggestion @CommonsWare, but it didn't work. Question updated with sample code.

Comment: Yeah, that's new to API Level 29 anyway -- I missed that in my original comment.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val intent = Intent()
val packageName = "com.google.android.documentsui"
val activityName = "com.android.documentsui.files.FilesActivity"

intent.component = ComponentName(packageName, activityName)

try {
    startActivity(intent)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    Log.e("FileManager", "startFilesManager: failed to start", e);
}
```

You could try this in kotlin

Comment: it works thanks but how do you put the Files app in the Download folder? That's where we need it

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna direct land on screen then the solution is -->

```
  Intent intentMain = null;
            try {
                intentMain = new Intent(this,
                        Class.forName("com.app.targetapp.MainActivity"));
                startActivity(intentMain);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```